# How to prevent unwanted string expansion in zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

For example, i need to call `echo` or `date` command:

```
~  echo "%k%M"
debs-e420"%k%M
~  date +%k:%M
debs-e42010:24
```

But if I run it in `bash` I'll get what I need:

```
$ date +%k:%M
10:25
$ echo "%k%M"
%k%M
```

So, how to prevent unwanted string expansion in zsh?

I'm using `zsh 4.3.17` and latest `oh-my-zsh`. Also, if I run `zsh` without `oh-my-zsh`, it works as expected.

Comment: Did you try another version? I'm using zsh 5.0.0, and it reacts the same way bash does.

Comment: @Dennis Actually, I'm new in `zsh`, and I'm not sure it's a `zsh` issue or `oh-my-zsh`. Because if I run `zsh` without `oh-my-zsh` I do not see any such issues.

Comment: Ah, OK. You should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Preface your command with `noglob`